# Read from a XFS brick, write on a volume?

Tags: glusterfs

Filesystem notifications are not available on volumes, the reason why we started reading directly from brick.

Is it okay to read directly from a brick, but write to a volume so that replication happens?

The volume is created using 3 bricks using a replication strategy. Could anyone please suggest the demerits of directly reading from brick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file on the brick from which you read is not in sync with the other copy/copies of the replica (i.e. there is a self-heal that is pending), you can get stale data. Reading from the mount ensures that you always get the up to date data.

Though not comparable with `inotify`,  you can use `glusterfind` to provide some level of filesystem notifications.